# Include Run Configurations in SVN project in MyEclipse

Tags: eclipse, subclipse, myeclipse

How can I configure MyEclipse and the SVN plugin (Subclipse 4.3.3) so that my Run Configurations are included in the source code control.  Every time a new developer checks out the project, he doesn't have the Run Configurations needed to test the application properly or to do the Maven packaging correctly.

Is there a way?

Comment: You can Export and Import Launch Configurations so you could put the exported data somewhere that can be checked in.

Comment: In the run configuration in the tab _Common_ for _Save as_ choose _Shared file_ (instead of _Local file_).

Comment: @howlger Thank you so much!  If you want to post that as the answer, I'll accept and upvote.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share your run/launch configuration, go to the launch configuration (***Run > Run Configurations...***) tab ***Common*** for ***Save as*** choose ***Shared file*** (instead of *Local file*).

In addition, you can choose to ***Display in favorites menu*** to add it to the drop-down of the corresponding button in the main toolbar.